# CiviEvent online registration and page not found for online registration

Tags: wordpress, civievent

After looooong time not working with CiviCRM I was asked for help and now, I am out of ideas.

I've created event with online registration without any entrance fee. Everything is setup properly, but page is not displayed after event link is clicked. I've checked online manuals for that and everything is (or I think it is) setup properly.

CRM is working with 4.7.3 wordpress. Event generated link looks like that:

subdomain.domain.pl/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=3

and as far as I checked, it should looks like

suddomain.domain.pl/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=3

I've checked Resource URL and there is no change in those settings.

Also, when I register as participant and check confirmation mail it has another link 
subdomain.domain.pl/index.php/2017/01/31/witaj-swiecie/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&id=2&reset=1

Any ideas why system generates me incorrect link to event registration?

Comment: If you add a short code to a WordPress page does the registration display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page or post with a shortcode is not mandatory. Something is probably amiss. Here are a few things to check:

- Is your WordPress install in a sub-directory. So the website is http://website.org but the WordPress files reside in http://website.org/wordpress. This can cause the direct links to result in a page not found.
- Check your WordPress base page under 'Administer>System Settings>CMS Database Integration' it usually is set to /civicrm (default you can change it to what ever you wish). Make sure that page exists. This is the page Civi uses as a template.

You want to get this straightened out. It can result in some issues depending on what you are doing with Civi. For example your opt-out links in mailings may not work correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And that was the main problem :) I forgot to check WP setting for direct links to pages and posts. Page CiviCRM exists, but there was discrepancy between addresses.  After I changed settings in CMS Database and Wordpress it is working perfectly :) Many thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Last time when I used CiviCRM (it was 4.6.4), page, or post was not mandatory.

After I create post with CiviCRM short code, everything works as requested. Thanks for guiding me to correct part of wordpress :)